# How to get the right id before create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm expanding upon M.Hartl's Sample twitter app.

What I've done is created a new model called Books. I want the books to be followable, like users, so if you are following a book you will see all comments associated with that book in your feed.

I have had minor success in creating the model, and following it. I can follow the book, say with id "2" and have the posts show in the feed. though when I try `follow a user with id 2`, I end up `following book id "2"` or get the `UNIQUE constraint failed` in my console. Another strange thing, if I destroy the relationship with both book and id "2" and just follow user "2", I actually get the users posts, though I can't unfollow the user from his button, I have to go to book "2" and unfollow from there.

Any ideas?

I'm thinking I need to have an if else check in my .create to make sure if Im on a book page I follow a book and not a user before committing to the database.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

here's some relevant code:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def feed
following_ids_subselect = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                           WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
Micropost.where("book_id IN (#{following_ids_subselect})
                 OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
end


# Follows a user.
   def follow(other_user)
   active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

# Follows a book.
   def follown(book)
   active_relationships.create(followed_id: book.id)
  end

# Unfollows a user.
   def unfollow(other_user)
   active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

# Unfollows a book.
  def unfollown(book)
  active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: book.id).destroy
  end

# Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
   def following?(other_user)
   following.include?(other_user)
  end

# Returns true if the current user is following the book.
   def followingn?(book)
   following.include?(book)
  end


 class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
  if current_user.follow(@user)
  else 
    @book = Book.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follown(@book)
  end
# respond_to do |format|
#   format.html { redirect_to @user }
#   format.js 
# end
end


class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :followed, class_name: "Book"

 validates :follower_id, presence: true
 validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: question i still a bit unclear can you share your follow table structure & model and explain what's the final result you want ?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I edited the post to show the follow info. Basically I want to follow books and users, so I can see comments associated with books and comments associated with users together on the user (who is following other users or books) page. Like when you follow someone on twitter, you see your posts + other peoples posts who you follow.

Comment: I think you have some issue with your follow table structure where you are saving books & users

Comment: Yes, what it is, is I think my create controller is confused? Does it look like it should work? are the if and else in the right spot? Basically I'm trying to create the relationship between user/user if I click the follow user btn on his page, or if im on a book page create user/book relationship. Like I mentioned in my post, there is confusion between params id:2 it doesnt know if im talking about book or user. I thought about saving user ids as odd numbers and book ids as even numbers.. though I think thats not the right way..

Comment: Can you share follow table schema ?

Comment: id, follower_id, followed_id, created_at, updated_at

Comment: class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "Book"
  
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end

Comment: Add a flag or field to differentiate for book and user

Comment: Or you can have different foreign keys for book and user to differentiate also.

Comment: can you show me an example?